# Warning Message on batch submission of matlab script on Linux-based cluster

Tags: parallelism, matlab

I recently began using a super-cluster at my university and have succeeded with serial matlab scripts. Now I am running code using parfor loops, and have been getting this warning in the .out file. I have tried everything I know to eliminate this warning about the task unexpected found in state:Unavailable.

The code generates correct output, but this is a concern.

Any ideas?  Should I go to the cluster administrator.

Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ...
[Warning: A task was unexpectedly found in state: Unavailable.] 
[> In parallel.cluster.Local/deriveJobStateFromTasks (line 29)
  In parallel.cluster.Local/getJobState (line 179)
  In parallel.cluster.CJSCluster/hGetJobState (line 358)
  In parallel.internal.cluster.CJSJobMixin/hGetStateEnum (line 144)
  In parallel.Job/get.StateEnum (line 238)
  In parallel.Job/get.State (line 230)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.CustomGetSet>iVectorisedGetHelper (line 128)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.CustomGetSet>@(a,b,c)iVectorisedGetHelper(obj,a,b,c) (line 102)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.CustomGetSet/doVectorisedGet (line 103)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.CustomGetSet/hVectorisedGet (line 76)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.GetSetImpl>iAccessProperties (line 322)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.GetSetImpl>iGetAllPropertiesVec (line 264)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.GetSetImpl.getImpl (line 133)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.CustomGetSet>iHetFunGetFunction (line 154)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.CustomGetSet>@(o)iHetFunGetFunction(o,props) (line 139)
  In parallel.internal.cluster.hetfun (line 46)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.CustomGetSet>iHetFunGetProperty (line 139)
  In parallel.internal.customattr.CustomGetSet/get (line 38)
  In parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient/pRemoveOldJobs (line 476)
  In parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient/start (line 317)
  In parallel.Pool>iStartClient (line 796)
  In parallel.Pool.hBuildPool (line 585)
  In parallel.internal.pool.doParpool (line 18)
  In parpool (line 98)
  In test_tph (line 5)]